# Razor helper with Dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to make Razor helpers with dependency injection to services? Or call some services from Razor view?

Thanks

Comment: Why not do that in your controller ?

Comment: I want to create clear helper for images. It creates image URL by dimensions. If image with dimensions not exist, I want to create it. If the logic in the controller, so it could be confusing, and I would have to iterate through product list in the controller (to create image urls) and then again in the view.

Comment: That definitely should be done in the controller like shyju said.  When you return you list and create a view model, you can check whether the image exists and create it then.  Creating it in the view breaks your separation of concerns in the the view should just display or send data back to the controller than then talks to the database or Web service.

Answer (score 3):

As of .NET Core, yes, they've added support for it; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection

E.g., it allows you to do something like;

```
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@using ViewInjectSample.Model
@using ViewInjectSample.Model.Services
@model IEnumerable<ToDoItem>
@inject StatisticsService StatsService
```

You'll note the `@inject` there at the bottom. The syntax is;

```
@inject <type> <name>
```

You'll also need to make sure that the type you want to inject is in your `ConfigureServices` class in `Startup.cs`